# Hbase Importtsv java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't read partitions file error

Tags: hbase, bulk-load

I have a distributed cluster and when a run a bulk upload command using importtsv it give me the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: Can't read partitions file error and moreover it has a local job runner running.
It imports fine from local system without specifying `-Dimporttsv.bulk.output` option
Any pointers on this will be really helpful

TIA

Comment: Please give more explanation about your problem or post the full command you tried